# Can somebody please explain to me about this line : '\n'.join([f"{n} x {i} = {n*i}" for i in range(1,11)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n= int(input())
print('\n'.join([f"{n} x {i} = {n*i}" for i in range(1,11)]))
```

and why can't I write like below?

```
n= int(input())
for i in range(1,11):
    x = ["{} * {} = {}".format(n,i,(n*i))]
print('\n'.join(x))
```

Comment: x needs to be a list
Initialize x = []

Comment: As you may be new to Python, explaining the solutions: (A) either create a list and `append` each "a x b = z" string to it, to replicate the original code, [as per @Ronin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344359/1431750) or (B) print each "a x b = z" string directly in the loop and not store each string in a list first, which imho, is the better way but not like the original code; [as per @pekpe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344281/1431750).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely do it the second way. You just have to fix the code a little, like this:

```
n= int(input())
for i in range(1,11):
    x = "{} x {} = {}".format(n,i,(n*i))
    print(x)
```

In a list comprehension, like the first example, you don't have the opportunity to print strings individually, so you join the list of strings together, separated by line returns, and the print the whole thing with one print statement.  In the second code example, above, you have the opportunity to call the print function repeatedly through each iteration, so you don't have to join the strings together.

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'.join` takes a `list` as a parameter. The latter code block passes in a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first code has list comprehension.The second one uses for loop.
The problem with the second code is that it does not have a list created in order to store the result of multiplication. x is creating new value inside the for loop every iteration.

Creating x as list outside the for loop and appending the result in the list to get the desired output.

```
n = int(input())
x = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    x.append("{} * {} = {}".format(n, i, (n*i)))
print('\n'.join(x))
```

Output:

```
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
2 * 5 = 10
2 * 6 = 12
2 * 7 = 14
2 * 8 = 16
2 * 9 = 18
2 * 10 = 20
```